# Contact image data not saving

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact

I have a phonelist application that loads employees from a database and lets users search through them.  They have an option to add the contact to their phone.  Currently I can add all of the data to the phone as a CNMutableContact(), but if I open up my iOS contact application the image data only works the first time I open the application.  If I open it later the images are gone, but all of the other information is correct.  Is there something I need to do for saving the image?  Does the image need to be stored locally aside from saving it through the save request?  The CNMutableContact uses a Data object for the image data.  Using Swift 4, iOS target 9.0+

```
let contact = CNMutableContact()          
contact.givenName = givenName
contact.familyName = familyName
contact.imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)

let store = CNContactStore()
let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()
saveRequest.add(contact, toContainerWithIdentifier: nil)

do {
    try store.execute(saveRequest)
} catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Is it (the image) missing only in your application, or in the default iOS Contacts application is missing too?

Comment: I load the image from a server in my application on load, I do not even attempt to store them locally.  The default iOS Contacts application will display the picture one time, then it disappears.

Comment: As far as I know, but this is for local images, the image remains in the contact even if you delete the image, so it seems that the contact is making a copy and save it somewhere else. But with not saved locally images it might be different.

Comment: thank you, I'll try saving it locally and see if that works for me